# In Sheets, can't remove name of deleted macro from list

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I deleted a non-working Sheets macro on my Scripts page, but the macro name is still in my Tools>Macros list (and I can't remove it).  I'm new at this and maybe I deleted it incorrectly.  Does anyone know how I can get it off the list?  Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Macros on Google Sheets are registered on the manifesto. If you removed through the editor instead of through the Google Sheets UI menus, then you should edit the manifesto manually or add/remove another macro by using the Google Sheets UI menus in order to trigger an automatic manifesto update.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for initially.  I was not aware of the manifest, but I can now see where I can also delete the "disconnected" title as well.  I also understand now that I should have used the Google UI to delete in the future (and not have to use the Manifest at all).  Very useful answer..thanks Ruben!

Answer (score 1):

did you try this:

### _______________

[image: 5]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I should have mentioned that I did try that series of steps (several times), and after completing them, when I re-displayed the list, the old macro name was still there. See my second post that this worked itself out.

Answer (score 0):

My problem solved itself.  Even with that defunct macro name on my list, I created a new macro.  When I looked at the list of named macros under Tools/Macros, the old macro name was gone and my new macro name was there (as it should be).  I didn't learn how to actually remove the old name, but the problem worked itself out.  I'm posting this in case another newbie like me runs into this same issue.  Cheers all!